# Dynamic select is not working for Guid name property

Tags: c#, select, dynamic-linq

I have simple class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}
```

I have `myClasses` query that contains one item: `new MyClass() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() }`

I'm trying to select Guid property from query :

```
var result = myClasses.Select($"new(Guid)");
```

But it is showing following exception:

> System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: ''.' or '(' expected'

It seems `Dynamic linq` is mixing up my `Guid` property with `System.Guid` structure. How can I solve this issue?

Note: It works when I rename property

Comment: Using `it` explicitly, e.g. `it.Guid` ?

Comment: using common linq `myClasses.Select(x => x.Guid)`? or if you like anonymous types: `myClasses.Select(x => new { x.Guid })`?

Comment: @IvanStoev It works, can you post it as answer ?

Comment: Glad it helped. The problem is that there are many builds of Dynamic LINQ library, all with different parsing support (`it`, `parentIt`, available methods etc.), that's why I wasn't sure if it would work or not. Feel free to post a self answer and include the information about the Dynamic LINQ package used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), you have 2 options:

1. Use **it**

```cs
var result = myClasses.Select($"new(it.Guid)");
```

2. Escape reserved name with a **@**

```cs
var result = myClasses.Select($"new(@Guid)");
```